# spark read parquet files from nested folders some of them are empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to read parquet files from all the sub-folders.
eg.,

```
\mnt\output\Reports\
\mnt\output\Reports\reportid=1
\mnt\output\Reports\reportid=2
\mnt\output\Reports\reportid=3

file_path = r'\mnt\output\Reports'
df1 = myspark.read.format("parquet").load(file_path)
df1.show()
```

These reports sub-folders are added as they get generated. In some cases, some of these could be empty. In such cases, I get the error "Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually."

Is there a way to skip these empty folders.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution for my issue..

```
df1 = myspark.read.format("parquet").option("recursiveFileLookup","true").load(file_path)
df1.show()
```